# Why is installation of MySQL on my mac is always halted

Tags: sql, mysql, macos, installation

I've been trying to install MySQL on my mac and an issue kept happening. I downloaded macOS 14 (x86, 64-bit), DMG Archive. Everything seemed fine until the final step. It says "the software was installed successfully" and then it's just frozen no matter what I do. The mysql is not installed at all if I force quit it. Please see the picture and help. Thank you very much!

I'm looking for a solution for this.

Comment: “Please see the picture.” What picture?